# Implementing user management using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to create an API for an external application using asp .net. This app will have users and I know that ASP.NET Core Identity is robust and will fulfill my needs.
Documentation guides me to create ASP.NET Core Web App ([documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNrKI.png), [visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5M0I.png)), but I can't use the same Authentication Type options if I want to create an ASP.NET Core Web API([visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdpRi.png)).

I tried to create an ASP.NET Core Web App using the Authentication Type needed and after that to add new API controllers([API Controller with read/write actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbPYe.png)). [The application works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmIYL.png) but I couldn't access the routes([GET from the browser fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27T4n.png)).

I googled it a lot, but I didn't find something that can help me.

Is there a possibility to do this, and if so, how can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Question starts with title about user management and ends with get API not accessible in browser. It's quite confusing what exact issue you are facing. if you could frame exact what issue you are facing, the community might be able to help.

Comment: I can fully understand what are you telling me, I put that GET call in context with what I tried. Sorry for ambiguous question.